# Quickly turn on/off bluetooth in an iOS 5 app

Tags: ios5, bluetooth

Is there an API (documented or not) that gives the possibility to turn bluetooth off or on in an iOS device running iOS 5?

I don’t want to release an app, I need to create one just for my personal needs.
(the idea for the app is this: you open it, if bluetooth is off, turn it on, otherwise, turn it off).

Answer (score 0):

Have a reverse engineering look at SBSettings plugin called:
BT Mono (Bluetooth Mono), which has the ability to change Bluetooth activation state.